# Android relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I've a `relative layout` in xml. I have to add some textview programatically to view, now I've to align a textview as alignparentright.I can do this only using `.addRule()` but I don't want to create a relative layout programmatically and then use this layer `object.addRule()`.Instead I've already added an id to relativeview in xml.

How do i use `addRule()` in this xml relative layer.I got the id in activity using `findviewbyid` and assigned to type textview but when i do `textview.addRule()`, this is not there for this relative layout type variable.

Comment: i don't understand the question, please rephrase and post some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, go like this

```
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_id);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    rl.addView(tv);
```

Any problem plz ask.

Comment: :I know above to do but I have clearly mentioned, I do n't want to create a new relative layout again.

Comment: in my answer where your are creating new relative layout, you are just accessing the layout in xml layout.

Comment: :You're using relativelayout.params, to which relative layout will this get applied.

Comment: that's only for rules, you are adding that rule to textview and adding this to relative layout ,s o it's ok,.Did u try this first of all ?

Comment: :Instead of wrap_content, can I pass 20dpi ?

Comment: I could n't add that, I added it like  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.20,LayoutParams.30);

Comment: you can do like this RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(20, 30);